# Where is the Cygwin NFS Server?

Tags: nfs, cygwin

Apparently Cygwin is meant to include an NFS server component. But, having tried numerous sources from the available list (when running Cygwin's Setup.exe) I cannot find the NFS Server anywhere. Is it still available somewhere or no longer part of Cygwin itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only in the 32bit version of Cygwin at present, so I assume you're installing and running the 64bit one.

Not everything has been ported to the 64bit builds.

As you can see from [this package search](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=NFS&arch=x86), the `nfs-server` package is present in the x86 build, but [from this search](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=NFS&arch=x86_64), not in the x86_64.

Comment: no longer available even in 32Bit Cygwin :(

Comment: Yep, looks like it got dropped.

Answer (score 2):

Two NFS Servers has been ported to Cygwin 64 
at the begin of May

https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-announce/2016-05/msg00046.html

https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-announce/2016-05/msg00047.html